# Seeking geocoding with advanced language support?

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding, internationalization

I'm building an address disambiguation page and I'm interested in having geocoding results returned in the local language of the country the result's in.

For example, if I make a reverse geocoding request for "Bucharest, Romania", I want the location returned to be "București, România" (the local name). If I have an ambiguous query, I want each result to be returned in the language of the country it's in. Say there was a Bucharest in the U.S, I'd want a search for "Bucharest" to return "București, România" and "Bucharest, U.S.A".

I've studied the Google Maps API, Yahoo! Maps and Bing Maps. Google is the only one that has [*some* language support](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) (see the `lang` parameter), but only for the entire resultset, as far as I understood. Bing and Yahoo! don't have any language support in their API.

Do you know of a way to do this? Is there any other service that supports this type of functionality?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If a user is using the UI in the language/culture of his choice, why would you return results in another language/culture?

Comment: Because of a limitation in a database I'm using. I have to do address searches, and address info is only in the local language. I can't change that, so I'm trying to offload it to the web-service :). I just found geonames.org, I may be sticking with that.

Answer (score 2):

Via Michelin 
http://dev.viamichelin.com/data/api-jsv2/geo1.htm

http://dev.viamichelin.com/web/api-javascript/documentation-v2#Geocoding

Via Michelin works well in Europe for language see http://dev.viamichelin.com/poi-rest.html lg = Language code (fra, deu, spa, ita, eng, ces, dan, nld, fin, int, nor, pol, por, swe)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PickPoint](https://pickpoint.io). It uses OSM data and can be configured to get back a response in default language (which is a language in what particular geodata was entered, commmonly in local language). If necessary you can specify desired language of a response.